# Shortening a oft-used code segment for testing a return value in Python

Tags: python, optimization

Consider this Python segment:

```
def someTestFunction():
    if someTest:
        return value1
    elif someOtherTest:
        return value2
    elif yetSomeOtherTest:
        return value3
    return None

def SomeCallingFunction():
    a = someTestFunction()
    if a != None:
        return a

    ... normal execution continues
```

Now, the question: the three-line segment in the beginning of SomeCallingFunction to get the value of the test function and bail out if it's not None, is repeated very often in many other functions. Three lines is too long. I want to shorten it to one. How do I do that?

I can freely restructure this code and the contents of someTestFunction however needed. I thought of using exceptions, but those don't seem to help in cutting down the calling code length.

(I've read a bit about Python decorators, but haven't used them. Would this be the place? How would it work?)

Comment: so just to calrify ... if a is None the function continues and returns something else?

Comment: Correct, "normal execution continues" means the function is doing something that it should only be doing when someTestFunction returned None.

Comment: Just a note that it's slightly less efficient to test "!= None" rather than "is not None" (see PEP290).

Comment: Why would you gratutitously confuse people reading your code? Sane answer is "don't do this" (imo).

Comment: Ali A, sorry, I didn't get your point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use a decorator, it would look like this:

```
def testDecorator(f):
    def _testDecorator():
        a = someTestFunction()
        if a is None:
            return f()
        else: return a
    return _testDecorator

@testDecorator
def SomeCallingFunction():
    ... normal execution
```

When the module is first imported, it runs `testDecorator`, passing it your original `SomeCallingFunction` as a parameter.  A new function is returned, and that gets bound to the `SomeCallingFunction` name.  Now, whenever you call `SomeCallingFunction`, it runs that other function, which does the check, and returns either `a`, or the result of the original `SomeCallingFunction`.

Comment: Thanks. Decorators look like most appropriate for my case, and this is a good explanation. hasen j offered a version of this, but I don't need to dynamically specify the test function, it's more clear to me if it's hardcoded. Good to learn about new stuff :)

Answer (score 4):

I often use a hash table in place of a series of elifs:

```
def someTestFunction(decorated_test):
    options = {
        'val1': return_val_1,
        'val2': return_val_2
    }
    return options[decorated_test]
```

You can set up options as a defaultdict(None) to default to None if a key isn't found.

If you can't get your tests in that form, then a series of if statements might actually be the best thing to do.

One small thing you can do to shorten your code is to use this:

```
if a: return a
```

There may be other ways to shorten your code, but these are the ones I can come up with on the spot.

Comment: Thanks. For someTestFunction, I don't care about length since the code is not repeated, so the series of statements is fine.

"if a: return a" is halfway there, but I still need to capture the return value of function into a. So we're down from 3 lines to 2. How can I push it further? :)

Answer (score 2):

I think this would do it:

**UPDATE** Fixed!
Sorry for yesterday, I rushed and didn't test the code!

```
def test_decorator( test_func ):
    def tester( normal_function ):
        def tester_inner():
            a = test_func()
            if a is not None: 
                return a
            return normal_function()
        return tester_inner    
    return tester 


#usage:
@test_decorator( my_test_function )
def my_normal_function():
    #.... normal execution continue ...
```

It's similar to DNS's answer but allows you to specify which test function you want to use

Comment: This isn't correct; test_decorator() will return the tester function, which will then be used as the decorator of my_normal_function. In order for this to work, you need another layer of function between test_decorator and tester.